# Как лучше сделать хранение и получение данных?

Tags: php, memcached

Опишу суть системы:

пользователь заходит на сайт (регистрация отсутствует) и проводит на нем время, оставляя ВРЕМЕННЫЕ записи на 10 минут, которые могут посмотреть и редактировать (точнее дополнять содержимое поста) другие пользователи.

- Проблема один: **где сохранять посты и дополнения к ним?**
  Мне кажется, что использовать базу здесь не нужно по причине скорости (активная запись/изъятия/удаления записей через малое время), а ограничится использованием кеша (memcached).
- Проблема два выплывает из предыдущей: **как идентифицировать записи пользователя?** (временные посты сгрупированые по пользователям отображаются на главной страничке (конечно, не совсем на главной, т.к. много постов - большая страница)).

Не будем углубляются в различные методы идентификации, а возьмем простой ip. *IP также сохранять в кеш?* Я плохо знаком с memcached, а буду изучать его по мере написания, поэтому спрошу наперед:

***как создать массив в memcached, где каждая запись хранит в нем разное число времени?***

Схематически опишу структуру такого массива на "С++":

```
struct el {
   ip, //идентификатор пользователя, заодно и связка с постами.
   time // время хранения
}

list<el> users; //сохраняет всех пользователей, которые на сайте
list.push_back( aпи и время ); //когда появляется новый пользователь, то добавим в базу в кеше.
После истечения time, запись с users автоматически удалится.
```

На главной станичке будут отображаться рандомные записи, связанные с идентификаторами, которые рандомно получаются из этого массива. ***Как получить их рандомно из массива в кеше?***
Спасибо за ответы.

Comment: Вы еще не реализовали свою задумку, а уже отказываетесь от БД. Вы производили замеры производительности? Нет? Тогда произведите, а потом уже решайте. Если вам так не хочется использовать реляционные БД, попробуйте NoSQL, mongodb всякие там, или key-value хранилища наподобии redis

Comment: @rikal, вы действительно упираетесь в то, что вам нужно совершать выборки, а никакой memcached этого поддерживать не может. Могу предложить вам просто создавать таблицы в памяти при запуске сервака, проблем с хранением и быстрым доставанием данных быть не должно.

Comment: @nolka, поcмотрите мой комментарий к ответу @Manitikyl. Уже очевидно, что нагрузка будет огромная.

Comment: @Etki, а вот это интересно. Это получается как бы обыкновенные таблицы mysql (или другой базы), которые созданны с помощью ENGINE=MEMORY? И ними можно работать до перезагрузки сервера mysql. Правда опять проблема с удалением записи и ссылок на запись через время.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL и создавалось для того, чтобы активно использовать данные и работать с ними, а не просто смотреть. Один-два запросика плюсом ничего не решат (даже 10). А через врем. память вы можете и проиграть.

Comment: @Manitikyl, хорошо. Пойдем от использования базы. Каждый пользователь сайта может просмотреть любые записи других пользователей (доступ к базе). Каждый пользователь может сохранить значения в базе, но при этом нужен еще cron для удаления записи из базы через 10 минут. Кроме того, дополнения к посту делают другие пользователи и это также запись в базу и извлечения с нее. После 10 минут нужно будет удалить все ссылки на главный пост. Итого использовать базу накладно.

Comment: @rikal, пока базу не юзают десять тысяч человек - это укладывается в стандартное использование.

Comment: @Etki, мне понравилась идея с memory table. Как я понимаю с активным извлечением/удалением/дополнением (на 10 тыс. человек) проблем быть не должно? Тогда почему, например, вк использует memcached, если бы можно было хранить часто используемые данные в memory table?

Comment: @rikal, мемкэш это для кеша. Т.е. есть какое-то постоянное хранилище, каждый раз его дёргать накладно, поэтому результаты обращений к нему кешруются в памяти на какое-то время. Memcached сильно проще (а значит надёжнее и быстрее) чем реляционные базы данных, и даже проще чем другие относительно простые nosql базы вроде redis-а. Проще он за счёт того что умеет только доставать значение по ключу и сохранять значение по ключу. Этого в самый раз хватает для кеша, но что-то большее на этом делать проблематично.

Comment: @rikal, а memory table - это полноценная (хотя, кажется, есть какие-то ограничения, но это детали) таблица в реляционной базе данных, со всеми ништяками. Но, я думаю, она будет ощутимо медленнее менее фичастых решений, хранящих данные в памяти. Вообще сейчас развелось много in-memory баз данных, так что если хочется заморочиться по производительности и нет нужды в сложных выборках и надёжном хранении, то стоит посмотреть в сторону таких баз данных.
С другой стороны, SQL это привычно, понятно и надёжно (в смысле mysql точно не загнётся через год, потому что инвестиции кончились).

Comment: @rikal, при чем тут контакт вообще? Что он хранит в мемкэше? Аналогичные данные? И выборки по ним делает? Ой ли.

---

И что это вообще за аргумент ad contactum в каждом втором вопросе? Ну пусть там себе что-то делают, если у вас нет четкого представления, почему это делается именно так, то и не надо к этому апеллировать, как к истине.